# Tampermonkey поля input с data-mask

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

Есть страница с большим количеством полей и 70% можно заполнить через скрипт, а вот 30% имею в строке ввода
 `data-mask="__________" data-mask_position="0"`
И как мне в них вписывать данные, не понимаю

Для заполнения формы использую вот такой скрип:

```
let b_searchField = document.querySelector("input.ui-textbox-input.js-textbox.js-textbox--email.placeholder");
b_searchField.value = "Наименование";
```

Но поля с `data-mask` не заполняются
P.S. В web'е чуть больше, чем 0

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @Олег с чего вы взяли что это не работает?

Comment: @ΝNL993 поле остается пустым

Comment: @Олег, у меня нет никаких полей которые остаются пустыми.

Comment: @ΝNL993 По идее там должны вписываться данные, но там остаются только " _ " равные количеству "_" в data-mask

Comment: Пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с тем, [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).